How to use Givens rotation for complex matrix?
I have a $A$ an hermitian matrix and i want to tridiagonalize it with givens rotation.
I found this :
QR factorization of complex matrix
I try it with this matrix :
$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
  4 & 2+3i & 1+4i \\
  2-3i & 5 & 2+i \\
  1-4i & 2-i & 6
\end{bmatrix}
$
I want to put a 0 at position $ A_{13} $ using $ A_{12} $ as a pivot.
I computed $s$ and $c$ as following :
\begin{align}
  norm &= \sqrt{|c_0|^2 + |s_0|^2} = \sqrt{\sqrt{(2^2+(-3^2)}^2 + \sqrt{1^2+(-4^2)}^2}=5.48\\
  s_0 &= \bar A_{13} = 1-4i \\
  c_0 &= \bar A_{12} = 2-3i\\
  \Rightarrow c &= \frac{c_0}{norm}=\frac{2-3i}{5.48}= 0.37-0.55i \\
  \Rightarrow s &= \frac{s_0}{norm}=\frac{1-4i}{5.48}=0.18-0.73i \\
\end{align}
I can now construct my rotation matrix :
$
G = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & c & s \\
  0 & -\bar{s} & \bar{c}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.37-0.55i & 0.18-0.73i \\ 0 & -0.18 -0.73i & 0.37+0.55i\end{bmatrix}
$
In order to put the 0 at position $ A_{13} $ i have to do $ A_{new} = S^{\dagger }*A*S $
I dont know why that doesnt work.
I have written a matlab script :
A =    [ 4   , 2+3i, 1+4i;
         2-3i, 5   , 2+1i;
         1-4i, 2-1i, 6];

fprintf('\n keyElement = s_0  = %8.2f + %8.2fi\n', real(A(1,3)), imag(A(1,3)));
fprintf('\n pivotElement = c_0  = %8.2f + %8.2fi\n', real(A(1,2)), imag(A(1,2)));


s_0 = conj(A(1,3));
c_0 = conj(A(1,2));
fprintf('\n s_0 value = %8.2f + %8.2fi\n', real(s_0), imag(s_0));
fprintf('\n c_0 value = %8.2f + %8.2fi\n', real(c_0), imag(c_0));

norm = sqrt(abs(c_0).^2+abs(s_0).^2);
fprintf('\n norm value : %8.2f\n', norm);


c = c_0 / norm;
s = s_0/ norm;
fprintf('\n c value = %8.2f + %8.2fi\n', real(c), imag(c));
fprintf('\n s value = %8.2f + %8.2fi\n', real(s), imag(s));


G = [ 1, 0, 0;
      0, c, s;
      0, -(conj(s)), conj(c);];
fprintf('\n rotation matrix \n');
disp(G);


test = G'*A*G;
disp(test);

And the output is :
$
test = \begin{bmatrix}
  4 & 5.11-1.46i & 0.73+1.09i \\
  5.11-1.46i & 7.63 & 0.06+0.83i \\
 0.73-1.09i & 0.06-0.83i & 3.37
\end{bmatrix}
$
while I would have liked to have this :
$
test = \begin{bmatrix}
  * & * & 0 \\
  * & * & * \\
 0 & * & *
\end{bmatrix}
$

The formula for $s$ is $-b/r$. You have forgotten the minus sign. Also, if you want to see the result of the Givens rotation, you need $G*A$, not $G'AG$. Lastly, Matlab has built in functionality for givens rotations, under the name 'planerot'. See my script below:

A =    [ 4   , 2+3i, 1+4i;
2-3i, 5   , 2+1i;
1-4i, 2-1i, 6];
G = eye(3);
G(2:3,2:3) =planerot([2-3i;1-4i]);  G*A


The formula for s should include a negative sign: $$s = -\frac{\overline{A_{13}}}{\text{norm}}$$`
To see the result of the given rotation, you need to compute $$
G^H A, \text{ not } G' A G.
$$

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The idea is to tridiagonalize a matrix in order to apply a Cuppen's algorithm to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the original matrix. That's why I do $G'AG$ to maintain the similarity of the matrix, thus preserving the eigenvalues of $A$ .
In fact, my error comes from my pivot; when using a horizontal pivot I need to apply this rotation matrix :
$
G = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & -\bar{s} & c \\
  0 & \bar{c} & s
\end{bmatrix}
$
And when i do this on my $A$ matrix i have this in result :
$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
  4 & 5.48 & 0 \\
  5.48 & 7.77 & -0.33-0.33i \\
  0 & -0.33-0.33i & 3.23
\end{bmatrix}
$
